# How to make a Machine Learning program learn how to calculate Average (Mean) on its own

Tags: machine-learning

For example

- input1 = [1,2,3] *expected Output = 2*
- input2 = [4,5,6] *expected Output = 5*
- input3 = [9,10,11,12] *expected Output = 10.5*
- input4 = [10,90,8,400,500,62,777,79,81] *expected Output = 223*
- input5 = [100,2,3,10, 30,200] *expected Output = 57.5*
- etc

Is there a common ML algorithm used for this kind of problem?

Is there a way I could use the **input lists as the only input** and have a program come close to a meaningful result?

I’m new to Machine Learning and my current approach would be to use the Sum of each list(x1) and Total number in a list (x2) in a linear regression model. But this way doesn't use the lists "as is" as the input.

Comment: What programming language? ML isn't really needed for a solution to that

Comment: I realized ML isn't needed but I would like a ML answer. Python (but any OO language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question re the mean: The sample mean problem is probably one of the oldest, if not the oldest, problem in machine learning ([Gauss-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem)). The solution, is a linear regression with equal values for all weights (1/N, where N is number of data points).

That being said, I appreciate your question, because it leads to "scalability" in the context of Machine Learning. Meaning that once you've learned the answer for the mean, through Gauss-Markov, you can introduce a non-linear function of the inputs and look for the optimal solution (e.g., single-layer feed-forward neural networks). So, I like your approach in learning Machine Learning this way. Keep at it.